# how to show the contacts stored in android mobile while typing like the messaging screen

Tags: android, android-contacts

I want to show the contacts stored in android mobile while typing text in a `EditText` box. I want to display the contacts below the `EditText` box like the messaging screen. I can retrieve the contacts using `ContactsContract`, but I don't know how to display like the messaging screen in Android. Does anybody know something about this?

My current code:

```
 Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                    null, null, null, null);
 if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        String id = cur.getString(
                        cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        System.out.println("contactsID-->>>"+id);
        String name = cur.getString(
                        cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        System.out.println("contactsName-->>>"+name);

        if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
            Cursor pCur = cr.query(Contacts.Phones.CONTENT_URI, null, 
                                   Contacts.Phones.PERSON_ID +" = ?", 
                                   new String[]{id}, null);
            int i=0;
            int pCount = pCur.getCount();    

            while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                String phoneNum = pCur.getString(
                                       pCur.getColumnIndex(Contacts.Phones.NUMBER));
                System.out.println("PhoneNum-->>>"+phoneNum);
            }

            // Query phone here.  Covered next
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) and use the contact names read from ContactsContract to populate the adapter. Code:

```
    String CONTACTS[] = null;
    Cursor contactsCursor  = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, new String[]{Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);
    if(contactsCursor!=null){
        CONTACTS = new String[contactsCursor.getCount()];//(contactsCursor.getCount())];
        int i=0;
        while(contactsCursor.moveToNext()) {
            CONTACTS[i] = contactsCursor.getString(contactsCursor.getColumnIndex(Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            i++;
        }
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, CONTACTS);
    AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
            findViewById(R.id.autocompleteTextView);
    textView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Hi aswin,i tried the code it wont dispalying the data in the autocompleteTextView.

Comment: I had tried this code out, it works. You should use the example in the link I provided, and modify the code as shown in the answer. Tell me where you are deviating, I might be able to help you.

Comment: I retrieved the contacts and set it to the adapter. but it is not displaying.I want to display the name and the mobile numbers while entering value in a editText box as like the messaging screen.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use an `AutoCompleteTextView` and populate it with your contacts. [DOC](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can use your own  class To store contact info  , customize this class as per your requirement   :-

```
public class History {
    private static final int VERSION = 1;
    private static final String FILENAME = "history.dat";

    private Context ctx;
    private ArrayList<String> list;

    public History( Context ctx ) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    public ArrayAdapter<String> getArrayAdapter() {
        return new ArrayAdapter<String>( ctx, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, list );
    }

    public void addUrl( String url ) {
        if (!list.contains( url )) list.add( url );
    }

    public int size() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public void read() {
        list = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream( ctx.openFileInput( FILENAME ));

            dis.readInt(); // VERSION
            int n = dis.readInt();

            while (n-- > 0) list.add( dis.readUTF());
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    public void write() {
        try {
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream( ctx.openFileOutput( FILENAME, 0 ));

            dos.writeInt( VERSION );
            dos.writeInt( list.size());

            for (String url : list) dos.writeUTF( url );
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

In your  main class  :

```
History  historyObject= new History(MainActivity.this)
while (cursor.moveNext()) {
    historyObject.addUrl(cursor.getString(0));
}
```

Use auto complete textbox  instead Edit Text

```
autocompleteText.setAdapter(historyObject.getArrayAdapter());
```

Hope it will help you :)